# WPF: DataTemplate not applied to dynamically added ListBoxItems

Tags: wpf, listbox, datatemplate, listboxitem

I'm creating a UserControl that contains a Listbox. I want the User to be able to add new Listbox Items through a ButtonClick. Adding the new Items works fine but it seems that my DataTemplate is not applied to the newly added Item.

This is how I assign my DataTemplate:

```
<ListBox  x:Name="UserControlListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsSource, ElementName=MyCustomListControl}"  >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="{Binding}" 
                       Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

This is how I add a new ListboxItem:

```
    public void AddItem(object listBoxItem)
    {
        IEnumerable enumerable = ItemsSource;
        List<object> asList = enumerable.Cast<object>().ToList();
        asList.Add(listBoxItem);
        ItemsSource = asList;
    }
```

I need a TextBox around my ListItem-Content in order to use the TextTrimming-Property. It works fine for the Items that are already inside the List that is assigned to the ItemSource Property of my UserControl but not to the ones that are added through the ButtonClick as you can see 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knWGA.png)

Comment: why not just add item to ItemsSource directly, guessing ItemsSource is observable ?

Comment: ItemsSource is a very bad name for a collection you're binding to.  As Muds says, make it an observablecollection if it isn't and .Add() to that rather than what you have there seems like a much better plan.

Comment: What else besides the ListBox is there in your UserControl? Instead of creating a UserControl you may consider to derive directly from ListBox and add additional elements in its ControlTemplate, i.e. set its Template property in XAML.

Comment: How do you call AddItem?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't binding ItemsSource to some collection in the code behind and adding items to the collection?